# mysql statement returns syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax-error

For some reason I get the following error when running the code below:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM postcodes_demographics INNER JOIN latlon1 on postcodes_demographics.postc' at line 3
```

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong, thanks for any suggestions!

```
INSERT INTO pslatlong
    SELECT postcodes_demographics.*, latlon1.*,
    FROM postcodes_demographics
    INNER JOIN latlon1
    on postcodes_demographics.postcode = latlon1.postcodens;
```

Comment: Remove the comma at the end of the `select` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an errant comma:

```
 SELECT postcodes_demographics.*, latlon1.*, <--- HERE
```

Remove it.

Answer (score 1):

I would be very surprised if merely removing the comma fixes the problem.  When using `insert`, you should get in the habit of listing all the columns explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO pslatlong(col1, col2, . . . )
    SELECT d.col1, l.col2, . . .
    FROM postcodes_demographics d INNER JOIN
         latlon1 ll
         on d.postcode = ll.postcodens;
```

You need to do this to be sure that the right column is assigned the right value, to allow auto incrementing columns to be auto-incremented, and to prevent problems based on the number of columns.

Answer (score 0):

This may works:

```
INSERT INTO pslatlong
 SELECT postcodes_demographics.*, latlon1.*
 FROM postcodes_demographics
 INNER JOIN latlon1
 on postcodes_demographics.postcode = latlon1.postcodens;
```